# How to save a registration number with slash in a full-text field PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I have a problem in saving registration numbers that contain slash in the name.
An example of an identifier is `ЦИК/1-3/20-0-0`. The analyzer for some reason breaks it into two parts.

```
word;   Word, all letters;   ЦИК
file;   File or path name;   /1-3/20-0-0
```

I check through the request.

```
SELECT alias, description, token FROM ts_debug('russian','ЦИК/1-3/20-0-0')
```

Moreover, if in the beginning there are Latin letters, then it analyzes the analyzer correctly. leaves the whole word whole.
I tried to change the configuration as follows.

```
CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION russian_test (PARSER  = pg_catalog.default )
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION russian_test
ALTER MAPPING
  FOR  asciiword, word, numword, asciihword, hword, numhword, hword_asciipart, hword_part, hword_numpart, email, blank, file
  WITH russian_stem;
```

Whatever variations I use, the word is always divided into two parts. Is it possible to get the correct Cyrillic alphabet processing from the analyzer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is done by the parser *before* any dictionary processing, and there is only one parser. You could write a new parser in C, but that is probably too hard.

Your best option is to use a [thesaurus dictionary](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-dictionaries.html#TEXTSEARCH-THESAURUS) to fix the damage done.

The dictionary would contain

```
ЦИК /1-3/20-0-0 : ЦИК/1-3/20-0-0'
```